# Why can I hear my heart beat louder after rigorous exercise

Tags: blood-pressure

As I understand exercise increases hear rate.   Why should an increase in hear rate feel like the heart is also beating louder (not just faster).  If I place my hand on my chest, I feel its thump much clearer after exercise.

So is exercise also making the heart beat more forcefully.  In which case, should the blood pressure change?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments. If you have an answer, please post it as such.

Answer (score -2):

[Stroke volume increases during exercise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Starling_law). So, your heart is actually larger wen you are exercising compared to when you are at rest. When you stop exercising, your heart will need some time to shrink to its normal size, so stroke volume will still be a bit larger than usual.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I don't see where your link states that exercise increases the size of the heart. Exercise increases stroke volume, but I don't think the mechanism in that case is increased LV size. I could be wrong but you haven't demonstrated it.

Comment: @CareyGregory [See 22 minutes into this documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GCAijt1mgI).